# Populating foreign key fields in Django

Tags: django, foreign-keys, template-inheritance

In my first app (course) I'm creating courses. Each course has number of chapters and each chapter has quiz. I'm trying to create quiz using second app (quiz). models.py (quiz) :

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    coursechapter = models.ForeignKey(CourseChapter)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=u'Quiz name',)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User)
    creation = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __unicode__ (self):
        return self.name

class Question(models.Model):
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=u'Question\'s text')


class QuestionAnswer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=u'Answer\'s text')
    is_valid = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class UserAnswer(models.Model):
    answer = models.ForeignKey(QuestionAnswer)
```

I have template for creating courses, inside that template i have link (Add chapters) which takes me to another template(view) for creating chapters. Inside i have link to create quiz for that specific chapter. That link leads to url: /quiz/new (using url.py from quiz app) which is represented by view.py (from quiz app) . 
**Problem** is i dont know how to get id of chapter for which I'm creating quiz. Example of chapter url (one before user click Create Quiz) /course/new/chapter/197/ , is it possible to somehow send chapter_id (197) through link or is there any other way?
views.py(Quiz):

```
class CreateQuizView(CreateChapterView):
    model = Quiz
    template_name = 'quiz/create_quiz.html'
    fields = '__all__'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.pk = kwargs.get('pk')
        return super(CreateQuizView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('quiz-list',
                                    kwargs={'pk': Quiz.objects.latest('id').id})

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):       

        context = super(CreateQuizView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

views.py(Course):

```
class CreateChapterView(CreateView, GroupRequiredMixin):
    model = CourseChapter
    template_name = 'course/add_chapter.html'
    fields = '__all__'
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.pk = kwargs.get('pk')
        return super(CreateChapterView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('courses-chapters',
                                    kwargs={'pk': Course.objects.latest('id').id})

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):       

        context = super(CreateChapterView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['chapter'] = CourseChapterForm
        context['chapters'] = CourseChapter.objects.all()
        context['last'] = Course.objects.latest('id')
        context['courses'] = Course.objects.all()
        context['action'] = reverse('courses-chapters',
                                    kwargs={'pk': Course.objects.latest('id').id})
        context['kw'] = self.kwargs
        context['quiz'] = QuizForm()
        context['question'] = QuestionForm()
        context['answer'] = QuestionAnswerForm

        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save()
        # chapters = CourseChapter.objects.filter(course_id=Course.id)
        return  HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

urls.py (main)

```
url(r'^course/', include('course.urls')),
url(r'^quiz/', include('quiz.urls', namespace="quiz")),
```

urls (course)

```
url(r'^new/$', course.views.CreateCourseView.as_view(),
    name='courses-new',),
url(r'^new/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', course.views.CreateChapterView.as_view(),
    name='courses-chapters'),
url(r'^edit/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', course.views.UpdateCourseView.as_view(),
        name='courses-edit',),
url(r'^new/chapter/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', course.views.CreateChapterView.as_view(),
        name='chapter-content',),
url(r'^edit/chapters/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', course.views.UpdateChapterView.as_view(),
        name='chapters-edit',),
```

urls (quiz):

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', quiz.views.ListQuizView.as_view(),
        name='quiz-list',),
url(r'^new/$', quiz.views.CreateQuizView.as_view(),
    name='quiz-new',),
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned that you have a link for creating quiz in your page where you create chapters. I suggest you create link right there itself.

For eg,

lets say you have course 'Learn Python' which has chapter called Introduction and it has id 7, you can format your url as such `/add-quiz/chapter/chapter_id`. You will have chapter in the page if you pass it from the view.

Comment: This is current link:     <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'quiz:quiz-new' %}">Create Quiz</a> How can i pass id from view? How should my url  conf look like?

Comment: <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'quiz:quiz-new' chapter.id %}">Create Quiz</a>, your urlconf can be /add-quiz/chapter/(?P<chapter_id>\d+)/. See it is given that you have chapter instance in this particular template.

Comment: gr8! One more thing, is it possible to pair up questions with quiz without creating quiz first ( foreignkey relationship) or do i have to make another view and template just for questions? Do u understand what I'm trying to ask u?

Comment: @ssapp I understand, see one approach is lets say you have a course, you want to add questions to it, now if there exists no quiz for that course you can take that question create a quiz in the views and attach that first question to the newly created quiz. So in essence, you have liberty to directly add questions just check if it has a quiz id if yes attach the question to that quiz else create a new quiz for that question and create a foreign key relationship

Answer (score 0):

Change your url format from `/quiz/new` to something like `/quiz/new/<chapter id>`.

You can fetch these `chapter id` from your `create quiz` view.

Comment: How can i fetch chapter id is what i dont get.. And is it possible to get id in that way so i can create quiz and edit it in same template?

Comment: In the create chapter api response, return one extra field called `chapter_id`.  use this chapter_id while calling create quiz api. thats it

Comment: you can pass this chapter_id like this <a href="{% url 'quiz:quiz-new' chapter_id %}" >